# What are the differences between JBOSS vs Tomcat - both as servlet container only?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jboss

Recently it occurred that an application had a Servlet defined in web.xml but that was never used. It was running fine in Tomcat, but when deployed on JBOSS, it started complaining with `ClassNotFoundException` and deployed failed. Error was

`Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.captcha.servlet.SimpleCaptchaServlet`

Am I right in thinking that Tomcat loads and initializes Servlets when required vs JBOSS does it at the the time of deployment ? Has it got to do with `load-on-startup` in `web.xml`? If so what the default values for Tomcat and JBOSS - I didn't specify any value to any of the servlets?

I read that JBOSS uses Tomcat and also understand it is a JEE container as opposed to just "Servlet Container". But what are the other differences - if any - in which JBOSS differs from Tomcat as a Servlet Continer ?

Comment: See "JBoss vs Tomcat again [closed]": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668042/jboss-vs-tomcat-again and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971939/jboss-or-tomcat/5989596#5989596  It seems JBOSS is Tomcat plus more (EJBs, JMS), so their behavior as far as when they load servlets should be the same I think.