# Tomcat can provide full implementation for Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have found that Tomcat can't serve the full functionality for Java EE; it's only a servlet container.
So if I want to add some more Java EE features I have to move to Glassfish or there is any other solution?

If I add some glassfish's .jar files to Tomcat's /lib folder can I then extend the features of Tomcat?

Comment: There is no such thing as J2EE anymore, its called Java EE! And there are other application servers besides Apache Tomcat and Glassfish, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_servers#Java_EE

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you want to have a look at [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/)

Comment: thak you for you reply.I have to install that differently or just I have to put the .jar that I'll get into my CATALINA_HOME/lib folder.

Comment: TomEE is a standalone server based on Tomcat and OpenEJB.

Comment: J2EE/JEE is only a specification. What parts from JEE you want to use? Depending on the answer there are many projects that can be used while developing applications that run on standard tomcat. For example JPA is part of the JEE spec and can be added to your applications through frameworks like Eclipselink or Hibernate.

Comment: It means I can install TomEE and if I dont want to insatll I can add more features to my application through framework that you said.

Comment: Depends on what features from the JEE spec you want to use (Persistence, Messaging, DI,...). There are a lot frameworks that implements parts of the JEE spec. And there are much more frameworks that implements functionality similar to that described in the JEE spec. Sometimes they implement it much better. But to give a precise answer you have to tell some more about what you want to achieve.

Comment: See also this post on what you don't get from plain Tomcat that is part of JavaEE (and TomEE) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269186/besides-ear-and-ejb-what-do-i-get-from-a-j2ee-app-server-that-i-dont-get-in-a/9199893#9199893