# Is there a way to determine the Java EE version at runtime?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Is there programmatic way to determine which version of the java ee environment is available?

Comment: You tagged Tomcat7. Just wanted to say, Tomcat7 isn't exactly a Java EE application server. It's "just" a JSP/Servlet container. Glassfish, JBoss AS and TomEE are examples of fullfledged Java EE application servers (JSP/Servlet/JSF/JPA/EJB/etc/etc).

Comment: Understood.  Mostly been using TomEE, but need to figure out is the right environment will be available during installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no standard way to do that.  The closest you could do is use reflection/ClassLoader and check for specific API classes/methods that were introduced in a given Java EE version.

Off the top of my head:

- Java EE 6 / EJB 3.1 added `javax.ejb.Singleton`
- Java EE 5 / EJB 3.0 added `javax.ejb.Stateless`
- J2EE 1.4 / EJB 2.1 added `javax.ejb.TimerService`
- J2EE 1.3 / EJB 2.0 added `javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean`

Before that it's J2EE 1.2 / EJB 1.1

Though, note, if this is for Tomcat (judging by the tag), the best way is to just check `System.getProperty("tomcat.version")`.  You should be able to imply the servlet version based on the Tomcat version.

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.

Comment: Tomcat versions and their supported APIs can be seen at https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there is a way to get the Java EE version number, but you can get hold of the Servlet API version number and the JSP version number:

- You can get the servlet api version in an implementation independent way from a `ServletContext` object.  Look for the `getMajorVersion()` and `getMinorVersion()` methods.
- You can get the JSP version as follows:

  `JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion()`

And there are no doubt platform (i.e. appserver) specific ways to find or infer various version numbers.

---

It is worth noting that "Java EE version" is a rubbery concept if you take into account what appserver vendors might do; e.g. cherry-picking the Java EE technologies that they support, and possibly cherry-picking versions.   For instance Tomcat does not support all of Java EE - EJB support is missing.

Comment: Note that `<web-app version>` in `web.xml` has influence in `ServletContext#getMajorVersion()` and `getMinorVersion()`. Theoretically, this can be set to 2.5 while the container itself supports 3.0. The container is then running in a fallback modus. This can if necessary be combined with checking if a Servlet 3.0 specific class (e.g. `@WebServlet` annotation) is in classpath or not, depending on why exactly the OP needs this information.

Comment: Note cherry-picking is not allowed on any certified Java EE server.  This was the main reason for creating [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org) as plain Tomcat excludes [quite a bit more than EJB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9199893/190816).

Comment: ServletContext has **four** relevant methods: `get[Effective]{Major|Minor}Version()'. See the JavaDoc for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Tomcat, you can get the [Servlet API version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) of runtime using [`org.apache.catalina.core.Constants`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/catalina/core/Constants.html) class. e.g.

```
if (Constants.MINOR_VERSION == 2 && Constants.MINOR_VERSION == 5) {
    // Servlet 2.5
} else if(Constants.MINOR_VERSION == 3 && Constants.MINOR_VERSION == 0) {
    // Servlet 3.0
} ...
```

Comment: There is a portable way to do this ... see my answer