# How to know the j2ee version?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

We are using Jboss5 GA Application server. Now the problem is Client is saying JDK we are using is 1.6 but j2ee version is 1.4. Can someone help me on these points below:

1 - Where do we define the j2ee version?

2 - how to check the J2EE version of any running application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420365/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-java-ee-version-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can check in jboss documentation which version of j2ee uses specific container(e.g jboss5 ga application server). 
Some part of j2ee components version and also java version you can check in properties -> project facets. Maybe you just need change your jboss lunch configuration e.g set different jdk location.